Render form inputs based on SharePoint list fields (Power App)
I want to make a dynamic form and list in the Canvas App to display the fields in the SharePoint list.
The idea is that I can change the datasource (the name of the list is the same, but there may be a different set of properties), and I need the form to adapt to this list.
The problem is that this list may differ, there may be a different set of properties, for example, in one case there may be (FirstName, LastName, Age), and in the second (FirstName, LastName), I cannot know in advance what fields will there be.
I think that I need to somehow get the list of properties that is in the SharePoint list, go through this property list in a loop and display input for each property. I have already spent several days searching for a solution but have not found it. Perhaps this cannot be done at all?
Maybe someone has done something similar and knows how to do it.

Hi Mccree, I am also learning things about PowerApps, I don't think Dynamic Form you mention can be possible, and even if it is possible it would be very difficult to keep things working as your app get further advance with functionalities. Forms control are directly linked with Data source and gets link with it since you add them on the screen and their DataCards are hardwired with the data source, so you can not switch  to different SharePoint list and dynamically change datacard's properties.

Not sue if it would work or not but you can try creating a generic Dataverse table (field1,field2,field3,...fieldn) and link it with your Form control. on dropdown change event, read your data from SharePoint list and save in  Generic table and finally show on your Form.
